# ssh connection and remote output in local shell

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, ssh

I would like to run a local command file remotely and get the output locally in my shell window.

Actually the command executes remotely but I do not see the results in my local shell/console window.

Any idea on how to implement the following command?

```
ssh user@host 'bash -s' < /Users/daniel/bin/bash/fz_multiple_db_connections.sh
```

Where fz_multiple_db_connections.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
connections=(
             'mysql -u dbuser__name      --password=passw   dbname ' 
             'mysql -u dbuser__name1     --password=passw1  dbname1')

for f in "${connections[@]}"
do
    echo `${f}`
    echo `mysql show tables`
    echo `mysql exit`
done
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll probably need to do `ssh -t ....` to allocate a tty. Programs that strictly write to `stdout` or `std::cout` should work fine without the `-t`, but if the program you're running needs access to `/dev/tty` (or any of it's equivalents), for example, to ask for a password or something, you need the `-t` option to `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

-v verbose output

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch07_03.htm